# WAR bundles SNAPSHOT JARs with timestamps

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I have this multi module project setup which uses Webstart and I need to bundle the WAR with SNAPSHOT JARs. When the JARs are bundled into the WAR, they are appended with a timestamp instead of the actual name. This is causing issues during their download.

```
Expected - ABC-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Actual - ABC-1.0-20141002.211448-2.jar
```

Env:

OS: Unix 
Maven: 3.2.1 
JDK: 1.7

I have already tried **useUniqueVersions=false** by defining a maven-war-plugin and setting this in the manifest configuration.

My webstart config:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-beta-6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>jnlp-download-servlet</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <outputDirectoryName>.</outputDirectoryName>
    <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
    <commonJarResources>
        <jarResource>
            ...
        </jarResource>
    </commonJarResources>
    <jnlpFiles>
        <jnlpFile>
            <templateFilename>JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP</templateFilename>
            <outputFilename>client.jnlp</outputFilename>
            <jarResources>
                <jarResource>
                    ...
                </jarResource>
            </jarResources>
        </jnlpFile>
    </jnlpFiles>
    <sign>
        ...
    </sign>
    <outputJarVersions>false</outputJarVersions>
</configuration>
```

Appreciate any inputs.

**UPDATE**
Adding details about the WAR plugin I added

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
```

The behavior continues. I read that maven 3 uses a unique snapshot system. But I am trying to work my way around it.

Also tried the following without any luck

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.baseVersion}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hm..you write maven-war-plugin is the problem but you show the configuration of webstart-maven-plugin ? Can you show the full pom file where you create your war file? Furthermore which version of maven-war-plugin do you use?

Comment: I don't have a specific definition for maven war plug-in in my pom. I have defined the packaging as WAR, maven should be using the latest version of the war plug-in.

Comment: [It is not the latest](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging). It is version 2.2 which is **not** the latest version. Furthermore you should alway pin the versions of the plugins. So please check this behaviour with particular version 2.4 of the maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The creators of the maven-webstart-plugin have accidentally inverted the meaning of the flag useUniqueVersions. When set to true it produces jars of the form -SNAPSHOT.jar and when set to false (the default) it produces jars of the form --.jar

I found that setting the useUniqueVersions flag to true in the maven pom configuration produced my desired results.

I needed it like this because when deployed with the datestamp version of the snapshots when trying to launch it I was getting a "Resource not found" error when it tried to get the snapshot jar it was trying to launch. Presumably this means that the servlet code itself is not set up to handle the different naming on disk, despite the fact that the specific datestamp version number does end up in the jnlp itself.